# I need an InfoPath form with People Picker fields to resolve ("Check Names") multiple default people

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I have an InfoPath 2013 form that I'm using in SP Online.  I have several People Picker fields with multiple people set as the default value (firstName lastName;firstName lastName;firstName lastName), and the person filling the form can add more people.

When the form loads, the form does not resolve the fields containing multiple people as the default.  The form does resolve individual names.  If someone clicks the "Check Names" button, then the field does resolve the names.

I need a way to get InfoPath to automatically resolve multiple names.  Can anyone suggest a way to do that?

I added the people as default values by selecting AccountID/Properties, and typing "firstName lastName;firstName lastName;firstName lastName" in the Default Value field.

I tried creating a rule that Queries the User Information List on Form Load and that didn't work.  Thanks.